# Use of undeclared type '' Swift ERROR

Tags: xcode7, xcode8

My swift project suddenly stoped working. It throws up the errors:

> Use of undeclared type 'GameScene'

and

> Use of unresolved identifier 'GameScene'

My GameViewController file is:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scene: GameScene!    //Use of undeclared type 'GameScene'

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)    //Use of unresolved identifier 'GameScene'
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

My GameScene file is:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var platform1: Platform!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 132.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    addPlatforms()
}

func addPlatforms() {
    platform1 = Platform()
    platform1.size.width = frame.size.width / 4
    platform1.position = CGPoint(x: platform1.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 8)
    addChild(platform1)
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you imported the module SpriteKit?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file, write `import SpriteKit`. `SpriteKit` is the framework that allows you to use `GameScene`.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I have imported SpriteKit in both files.